# __hash__ not being called when using instance as key

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, key, built-in

I have searched SO and found numerous questions about this very topic, and I've tried recreating accepted answers, but I am unable to duplicate the output shown.

```
>>> class testFoo(object):
...     def __init__(self,x):
...         self.x = x
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return hash(self.x) == other
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return hash(self.x)
...
>>> d = {}
>>> x = testFoo("a")
>>> d[x] = 1
>>> d
{<__main__.testFoo object at 0x7f6d9ccc5550>: 1}
>>> hash(x)
12416037344
>>> hash("a")
12416037344
>>>
```

What I expected to see when I typed "d" above is a key "a", not the **repr** string for the object.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the key is the object and you haven't overriden the default `__repr__`.

You would need to add this to `testFoo` class.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.x
```

Comment: doh!  Thanks!  Put in there, and it works as expected.